# Error when running pyrouge

Tags: python, python-3.x, summarization

I installed pyrouge on windows 7 (python3.6).
When trying to excute the method `convert_and_evaluate()` of the class `Rouge155`
i got this error:

`OSError: [WinError 193] %1 n'est pas une application Win32 valide`